# Trim by 2nd to last Instance of Character in String

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to trim a string down using `MID` such that everything after the **second to last instance** of `/` is removed.

```
mom/dad/brother/sister/me/   to     mom/dad/brother/sister/
thor/ironman/thanos/         to     thor/ironman/
```

I am trying to use combination of `Mid`, `Left` and `InStrRev` but am likely over thinking this. What I have is below and nothing is happening....

```
For i = 2 to LR
     dq.Range("U" & i) = Mid(dq.Range("U" & i), 1, InStrRev(Mid(dq.Range("U" & i), 1, Len(dq.Range("U" & i) - 1)), "/", -1, vbTextCompare))
Next i
```

I'm guessing the issue is with `InStrRev`

Comment: That's quite a mouthful. Try splitting up that clever one-liner into smaller instructions. Debugging will be much easier then.

Comment: I had my `-1` in the wrong part of `LEFT`. After that I got a diff error which was resolved after removing `vbTextCompare`

Comment: I think `Join` and `Split` should work nicely here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Split

```
    For i = 2 To LR
        Dim spltStr() As String
        'Split the string on the "\"
        spltStr = Split(dq.Range("U" & i), "/")
        'Remove the last two
        ReDim Preserve spltStr(UBound(spltStr) - 2)
        'Join the array with "/" as the delimiter and add the extra on the back
        dq.Range("U" & i).Value = Join(spltStr, "/") & "/"
    Next i
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - converted this to a range loop and it's much cleaner. This approach is def better than my first attempt. On a time crunch so rushed this one

Answer (score 1):

*@Craners solution also works and is much faster*

---

### Issue with my approach:

1. `Len(Range - 1)` is invalid. This should be `Len(Range) - 1`
2. Removed `vbTextCompare`

The below returns correct results to trim a string up-until & inclusive of the 2nd to last instance of a character.

```
Mid(dq.Range("U" & i), 1, InStrRev(Mid(dq.Range("U" & i), 1, Len(dq.Range("U" & i)) - 1), "/", -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice little function that does the trick

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestStrip()

    Debug.Print Strip("mom/dad/brother/sister/me/", "/", 2)
    Debug.Print Strip("thor/ironman/thanos/", "/", 2)

End Sub

Function Strip(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Seperator As String, ByVal StripCount As Long) As String

Dim myArray As Variant
Dim mySeperatorCount As Long

    mySeperatorCount = Len(Source) - Len(Replace(Source, Seperator, vbNullString))
    myArray = Split(Source, Seperator, mySeperatorCount - StripCount + 2)
    Strip = Left(Source, Len(Source) - Len(myArray(UBound(myArray))))

End Function
```